# What happens when Armour Level equals Penetration Level exactly?

Tags: combat, armor, ghost-ops

I have the original version of Ghost Ops (which uses Fudge dice), not the Savage Worlds version or the OSR version. This question is about that original version, but if you think the rules in one of the other versions can throw some light on this, please chip in.
I’m hoping there is clarification for this question in one of the expansions, or in an updated version of the pdf (I only have a print copy). I’ve failed to find any errata on the internet.

On page 108 of the core rulebook, it says this about Armour:

> If the Armour Level is less than the Penetration Level of the bullet then no armour is rolled as the bullet has ignored it. If the Penetration Level is less than the armour level then that amount of armour is ignored.

So…

- If a Penetration Level 3 bullet hits Armour 2, then no armour roll
  and the bullet does full damage.
- If a Penetration Level 1 bullet hits Armour 2, then the armour becomes 2 -1 = 1. And then an armour roll is made to see how much the armour reduces the damage.

What happens when a Penetration Level 2 bullet hits Armour 2?

Comment: Is there any difference mechanically between "armor 0" and "no roll"?

Comment: @BenBarden Seems like the kinda thing someone with experience with the system will know. Hopefully it will be touched on by a good answer to this question :)

Comment: @BenBarden  That's one of the game mechanics which there is no example for. I have no idea if there's a difference between (1) your armour being 0 because you aren't wearing armour, and (2) your armour being zero because 2 armour -2 = 0.